# SQL Server can't login in any user by SQL Authentication

Tags: sql-server, users

So I just installed SQL Server Developer and SQL Management Studio in my personal computer.

I have worked with SQL Server before but I never had to install and configure one so I was quite lost.

The issue that I was having was that I could not connect with any user using SQL Authentication. I would try to connect with the SA user and it would fail.

I looked up on the internet and I found people suggesting changing the Server Security properties from Windows Auth only to Windows and SQL Authentication. I did that and I also enabled the SA user login but still I could not connect using the SA user.

I talked to some friends of mine who are also programmers and found other people who had the same issue and simply gave up.

Answer (score 0):

After giving up for the day, turning off my machine and coming back the next day I decided to try something different.

Until then I was trying to set the SA user's password to "123" and it kept on failing to connect. So I decided to try using a stronger password. I tried to change the password to "password123" and it worked first try.

I found that really weird since there was no feedback to me saying that the password I was trying to use was too weak.

Anyway, that's how I solved my problem.

Comment: "*I found that really weird since there was no feedback to me saying that the password I was trying to use was too weak.*" - For future reference, login failures are intentionally vague in description to the client app that's trying to connect for security reasons. The actual root error code can be found in the SQL Server Logs.